# Expo Developer Tools: Error loading devtools, no scheme specified for development client

Tags: javascript, react-native, expo

[image]

May I know what to do with this error? I just typed expo start in the terminal and this error appeared. I am new to mobile development and react native expo.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.